# What Object Did Marilyn Take and What Does it Mean?

Tags: character, analysis, longmire

In a scene of the final episode of the TV series ***Longmire*** (*Goodbye Is Always Implied*), the reoccuring character, a Crow Medicine Woman named **Marilyn Yarlott** (Tantoo Cardinal) is in the Police Station and swipes an **inanmate object** off of another character's desk. It seems like it was some kind of office-tool, but I'm not sure.

[image: Marilyn]

So my question is, **What object did she take and is there any signifigance** or **symbolism** in the object *other than* it feeds into the dichotomy of the character walking the line between a wise riddling Medcine Women with some magical abilities and spiritual insights vs a bit of a shady con women?

Answer (score 2):

After a rewatch and finally finding a screencap, it turns out she did swipe a vintage stapler. Something similar to an pilot stapler.

[image: Longmire 6.10]